# Julia : How to copy an error message from Juno in Atom?

Tags: error-handling, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

Sorry for this very basic question but how is it possible to copy an error message from `Juno` in `Atom` using `Julia`. I tried to highlight the message but as soon as i hit `CMD + c` (on a `Mac`) the highlighting disappears and nothing is being copied

Comment: Is your copy/paste working normally for other apps?  I see several [comments about OSX copy/paste issues](http://osxdaily.com/2018/02/02/fix-copy-paste-not-working-mac/).

Answer (score 2):

I normally paste the command to the Atom Julia console and copy the error message from the console. One advantage of this is that the console displays error message opposed to an `Error` object displayed by Atom.

However, on Windows this also works:
- hold left-mouse button to make the selection, do not release the mouse button
- press `Ctr+C` while still holding the mouse button

Comment: Thank you @PrzemyslawSzufel. I was used to the hydrogen environment with python where you can indeed copy paste the message (but you don't have a console)

Comment: It helps a lot. However it could still be convenient to be able to copy directly the message from the juno